# CSS transform translate in Messenger app

Tags: css, facebook

I use this code to center a div vertically and horizontally:

```
#divname {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

It works in most browsers mobile and desktop, and when opened in the Facebook app internally it looks good.

But when the link is opened with the Facebook Messenger app, the `transform: translate` CSS rule doesn't work.

How to make this work for Facebook messenger app?

Comment: By any chance, have you found the solution? Seems like I'm stuck with the same problem of Facebook in-app browser completely ignoring transform: translate options...

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot but you could try reordering *transform* properties because browsers may have different implementations for the actual property and the vendor prefix: ([Source](https://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/))

```
#divname {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

You could also try flex, now that it has [decent support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    I'm centered both vertically and horizontally
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ptbnb7d/2/)